VS Code (oracle developer tools) commits even with autocommit off
It might be a stupid question, but I was wandering whether it is expected behavior that when I run a PL/SQL block, the changes are commited to the database. The autocommit is disabled and the results page does NOT write "commited". But when I try to rollback, nothing happens.
I was previously working in Toad where the behavior was different, I had to commit manually (or in the code).
I ran "set autocommit off" even from the file, but the behavior prevails.
EDIT:
An example of a block that is commited is a simple delete:
BEGIN
    DELETE FROM jobs
    WHERE
        j_id = 9;
END;
/


Can you share that piece of PL/SQL code? Does it, by any chance, contain dynamic SQL (i.e. EXECUTE IMMEDIATE) which runs some DDL which implicitly commits?

Some commands (e.g. TRUNCATE TABLE ...) perform an implicit commit. Do you run such commands in your PL/SQL block?

Even simple inserts, updates, deletes do this committing. I have updated the question to include an example block.

This (https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/developer-tools-for-vscode/getting-started/disabling-and-enabling-auto-commit.html#GUID-2481EC33-EA26-4E73-AD4A-749372B14329) is document that describes how to disable/enable autocommit. Reading what you said so far, I guess you already did that, but ... just in case you didn't, have a look.

Yes, I have already done that, but thanks anyway.

Hi,  you see this only when you execute the DML in a SQL block or you see when you run a single DML statement , say delete but don't commit, are you able to select those rows that were delete or no.

I saw it even when running a single DML statement. The behavior was however even weirder. When I had created a database link, the changes didn't autocommit. But for tables in the scheme they did.

I have out of desperation restarted VS code and it seems to be working now. I hope it stays this way, but still do not feel that comfortable, since I do not know what had caused it.
